# What is netfx preprocessor directive and how to activate it?

Tags: c#, .net, compilation, task-parallel-library, easynetq

EasyNetQ source code uses NETFX compilation symbol to utilize an improvement\fix regarding TPL library as follow:

```
#if NETFX
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>();
#else
            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
#endif
```

The question is where this symbol is defined and how the following execution path could be activated?:

```
 var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<T>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
```

**UPDATE**:
I have found that it introduced in https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/pull/760 but still don't know what is it exactly.

**UPDATE2**:
It seems that it is a default symbol defined based on target framework to distinguish fulll framework and core builds but I can't find it in any documentation about it. I need to know as a library consumer, how to activate it to direct execution path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that it would be used to distinguish between the .NET Framework (NETFX) and other environments like .NET Standard and .NET Core.

Like all compilation symbols in C#, it would be defined in the project settings and would likely appear in a build configuration targeting the .NET Framework (and not appear in other build configurations). To activate it, therefore, you would just change the active build configuration for the project.

Comment: I can't find it in build configuration, it seems that it is a default symbol defined based on target framework to distinguish fulll framework and core builds but I can't find it in any documentation about it.

Comment: @mehran There are no default symbols in VS or the C# compiler. If you create a new console application project and try to use the NETFX symbol, you will see that it is not defined.

Comment: Yea I introduced it in ENQ. it's a custom directive defined in the csproj file. if you want to use the directive-specific code from ENQ in your library, reference the full .net framework assembly. If you want to use the directive in your project, just redefine it in your own csproj file.

Comment: @WiebeTijsma thanks, why I can't see it in EasyNetQ project, "conditional compilation symbols"?

Comment: I have to check, but can't until next week. it's possible we removed it already if we're only compiling for .NET standard 2.0 now. It should be very trivial to add it to your own project though.